# how to generate documentation for msg/srv files using rosdoc

Tags: ros, rosdoc, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to generate Msg/Srv API documentation for my local ROS package. I run

```
$./rosdoc -o docPATH <package>
```

But I only see documentation for autogenerated code from srv.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11128/how-to-generate-documentation-for-msg/srv-files-using-rosdoc/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you run rosmake before running rosdoc?  The msg and srv documentation requires the generated outputs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2012-01-08**:
sorry i just noticed that the documentation for srv had already been generated... in a separated folder '/srv'